# Match upload spreadsheet columns to table columns

Tags: sql, oracle, upload, spreadsheet, oracle-apex

I have a spreadsheet upload option in my APEX application, and have code that parses through the data and uploads it to a table. 

I am trying to find a way to match the spreadsheet columns with the table columns in case the user switches columns around.

The below code is what I use to parse through the data, but I have been unable to figure out how to match spreadsheet column1 to table column1.

```
DECLARE  
v_blob_data       BLOB;  
v_blob_len        NUMBER;  
v_position        NUMBER;  
v_raw_chunk       RAW(10000);  
v_char      CHAR(1);  
c_chunk_len   number       := 1;  
v_line        VARCHAR2 (32767)        := NULL;  
v_data_array      wwv_flow_global.vc_arr2;  
v_rows number;  
v_sr_no number := 1;
v_first_line_done boolean := false;  
BEGIN  
delete from TEMP_UPDATE;  
-- Read data from wwv_flow_files</span>  
select  
blob_content  
into v_blob_data  
from wwv_flow_files  
where name = :P2_FILE_UPLOAD;
/* last_updated = (select max(last_updated) from wwv_flow_files where UPDATED_BY = :APP_USER)  
and id = (select max(id) from wwv_flow_files where updated_by = :APP_USER); */  
v_blob_len := dbms_lob.getlength(v_blob_data);  
v_position := 1;  
-- Read and convert binary to char</span>
WHILE ( v_position <= v_blob_len )  
LOOP  
v_raw_chunk := dbms_lob.substr(v_blob_data,c_chunk_len,v_position);  
v_char :=  chr(hex_to_decimal(rawtohex(v_raw_chunk)));  
v_line := v_line || v_char;  
v_position := v_position + c_chunk_len;  
-- When a whole line is retrieved </span> 
IF v_char = CHR(10) THEN  
    -- Convert comma to : to use wwv_flow_utilities </span>  
    v_line := REPLACE (v_line, ',', ':');  
    -- Convert each column separated by : into array of data </span>  
    v_data_array := wwv_flow_utilities.string_to_table (v_line);
    -- Insert data into target table </span>   
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into TEMP_UPDATE (ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR,FIVE,SIX,SEVEN) values (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7)'       
    USING v_data_array(1), v_data_array(2), v_data_array(3), v_data_array(4), v_data_array(5), v_data_array(6), v_data_array(7) ;  
    -- Clear out  
    v_line := NULL; v_sr_no := v_sr_no + 1;
END IF;  
END LOOP;
DELETE FROM WWV_FLOW_FILES where name = :P2_FILE_UPLOAD; 
--DELETE FROM TEMP_UPDATE WHERE PCFN LIKE 'P%'; 
--UPDATE TEMP_UPDATE SET USERNAME = REPLACE(USERNAME, ' ', '');
END;
```

Can anyone help out with this?

Thanks
Steven

Comment: I would take a different approach altogether.  I would compare the column headers with what they should be.  If they don't match, reject the file and tell the user to do it again.  Having columns in an unexpected order is not the only undesired result out there.  There might be no column headers, or a completely different spreadsheet.

Comment: I thought about that too, but 1. I wasn't sure how to do that either, and 2. I wanted to see if matching the columns wasm't too difficult becauser I'm not sure if my customer will like to have to upload the spreadsheet over and over (even though it is their fault they switchted the order). Any chance you would have an example of how to check the order of the columns before the spreadsheet any data is parsed into the table?

Comment: I do this stuff with ColdFusion, not apex.  My logic would be to start with a list of expected values for the column headers.  Then I would loop through the list and compare the expected value to the actual value.  If they didn't all match, I would reject the record.  At some point, you have to validate the data as well so that you don't get 'one' in a numeric field.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to match the columns upon parsing instead of rejecting the spreadsheet. Hopefully someone can help out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to post the final code after I figured out how to look at the column order first:

```
procedure MM_IN_PARSE
is

begin

DECLARE    
v_blob_data       BLOB;    
v_blob_len        NUMBER;    
v_position        NUMBER;    
v_raw_chunk       RAW(10000);    
v_char      CHAR(1);    
c_chunk_len   number       := 1;    
v_line        VARCHAR2 (32767)        := NULL;    
v_data_array      wwv_flow_global.vc_arr2;    
v_rows number;    
v_sr_no number := 1;  
v_first_line_done boolean := false;  
v_error_cd number :=0;  
v_quote_pos1 NUMBER;  
v_quote_pos2 NUMBER;  
v_enclosed_str VARCHAR2(200);
v_errmsg VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN

delete from TEMP_MM_UPDATE where username = v('P1_USER_ID');

-- Read data from wwv_flow_files</span>    
select    
blob_content    
into v_blob_data    
from wwv_flow_files    
where name = v('P2_FILE_UPLOAD'); 

v_blob_len := dbms_lob.getlength(v_blob_data);    
v_position := 1; 

-- Read and convert binary to char</span>  
WHILE ( v_position <= v_blob_len )    
LOOP 
--BEGIN
v_raw_chunk := dbms_lob.substr(v_blob_data,c_chunk_len,v_position);    
v_char :=  chr(hex_to_decimal(rawtohex(v_raw_chunk)));    
v_line := v_line || v_char;    
v_position := v_position + c_chunk_len;

-- When a whole line is retrieved </span>   
IF v_char = CHR(10) THEN

v_line := REPLACE (v_line, '>', NULL);
v_line := REPLACE (v_line, '<', NULL);

LOOP  
--Make sure there's something to replace  
IF INSTR(v_line, '"', 1, 1) = 0 THEN  
EXIT; -- If nothing to replace, exit loop and don't try  
END IF;  
--Find the position of the first and second quotes in the line of text  
v_quote_pos1 := INSTR(v_line, '"', 1, 1);  
v_quote_pos2 := INSTR(v_line, '"', 1, 2);  
--Extract the inner string  
v_enclosed_str := SUBSTR(v_line, v_quote_pos1 + 1, v_quote_pos2 - v_quote_pos1 - 1);  
--perform the replacement  
v_line := SUBSTR(v_line, 0, v_quote_pos1 - 1) || REPLACE(v_enclosed_str, ',', '<') || SUBSTR(v_line, v_quote_pos2 + 1);  
END LOOP; 

-- Convert comma to : to use wwv_flow_utilities </span>
v_line := REPLACE (v_line, ':', NULL);
v_line := REPLACE (v_line, ',', ':');  
v_line := REPLACE (v_line, '<', ',');  
v_line := REPLACE (trim(v_line), '-', NULL);  
v_line := REPLACE (trim(v_line), '', NULL);  
--v_line := REPLACE (trim(v_line), '"', NULL);  
-- Convert each column separated by : into array of data </span>    
v_data_array := wwv_flow_utilities.string_to_table (v_line);  
--Check to see if the row of column headers has already been parsed through  
IF(v_first_line_done != true)THEN   
v_first_line_done := true;  
--Check column order in spreadsheet  
IF(v_data_array(1)      LIKE '%Username%' AND
        v_data_array(2)  LIKE '%NDN%' AND
        v_data_array(3)  LIKE '%PCFN%' AND
        v_data_array(4)  LIKE '%TCN%' AND
        v_data_array(5)  LIKE '%Primary Sea/Air%' AND

        v_data_array(7)  LIKE '%Customer%') THEN   
    v_error_cd := 0;  
    v_line := NULL;  
ELSE  
    v_error_cd := 1;  
END IF;  
--If first line is done and the column order is correct then  
ELSIF(v_first_line_done = true AND v_error_cd = 0 AND v_data_array(1) is not null) THEN   
-- Insert data into target table </span>    
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into TEMP_MM_UPDATE   
(USERNAME,
  RPT_FLAG,
 PCFN,
 TCN,
CUSTOMER)
values (:1,:2,:3,:4,:7)'   
   USING   
v_data_array(1),   
v_data_array(2),   
v_data_array(3),   
v_data_array(4),   
v_data_array(7);    
   -- Clear out    
    v_line := NULL; v_sr_no := v_sr_no + 1; 

END IF;  
 END IF; 

/*EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS then
v_errmsg := SQLERRM;

v_errmsg := REPLACE(v_errmsg, 'ORA-12899: value too large for column "APEX01"."TEMP_MM_UPDATE".', '');
v_errmsg := REPLACE(v_errmsg, '"', NULL);
v_errmsg := REPLACE(v_errmsg, '(actual:', ' value too large. (current length:');
v_errmsg := REPLACE(v_errmsg, 'maximum:', 'maximum length:');

v_errmsg := REPLACE(v_errmsg, 'ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column', 'Numeric value to large for the column.');

v_errmsg := REPLACE(v_errmsg, 'ORA-01722: invalid number', 'Invalid value in a column expecting a number.');

v_errmsg := REPLACE(v_errmsg, 'ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected', 'Check all date column values for a non-date value.');

v_errmsg := REPLACE(v_errmsg, 'ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string', 'Check all date column values.');

v_errmsg := REPLACE(v_errmsg, 'ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month', 'Not a valid date day.');

v_errmsg := REPLACE(v_errmsg, 'ORA-01843: not a valid month', 'Not a valid date month.');

v_errmsg := REPLACE(v_errmsg, 'ORA-01861: literal does not match format string', 'Invalid value format.');

insert into temp_NDN_update (username,pcfn,tcn,error_desc)
values (v('P1_USER_ID'), v_data_array(3),v_data_array(4), v_errmsg); 
v_line := NULL; v_sr_no := v_sr_no + 1;

END;*/

 END LOOP;

DELETE FROM WWV_FLOW_FILES where name = v('P2_FILE_UPLOAD');
 IF(v_error_cd = 1) THEN  
INSERT INTO temp_mm_update (USERNAME, ERROR_DESC)  
VALUES (v('P1_USER_ID'), 'Error. Please check column order in spreadsheet.');  
END IF;

/*EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
insert into temp_mm_update (username,error_desc)
values (v('P1_USER_ID'), 'No Data Found.');*/


END;
```